# How to cluster a finite number of random variables based on their distributions?

Tags: distributions, random-variable, cluster-sample

Suppose that we have $n$ mutually independent (not i.i.d.) random variables $X_1,\dots,X_n$. We assume that these random variables can be divided into $k$ distinct groups ($k<n$), where in each group, all random variables that belong to that group are identically distributed.

**Example:** There are 10 random variables that can be divided into two groups, where the first group contains four random variables that are i.i.d. with a distribution that has the mean and variance of 4 and 23; and second group contains six i.i.d. random variables that the mean and variance of their distribution is 8 and 66.

**Problem:** Suppose that the number of groups and the distributions are unknown. Now, let us make $t$ observations for those $n$ random variables, where each observation is a vector $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$. At the end, we will have a $n\times t$ matrix $M$, whose column $i$ corresponds to $t$ different i.i.d. samples for $X_i$. Using matrix $M$, we want to divide the random variables into $k$ groups based on their distributions.

**Question:** How can we find the number of groups and the variables that belong to each group?

You may assume that the distribution of each r.v. is a Gaussian mixture and that $k$ is less than a known number, e.g., $K$.

Comment: Reposting a question doesn't make it any more answerable than it was originally!  Please edit your first question.

Comment: I have edited the original question. If you read it carefully, I have modified the explanation of the problem and I have also added an example.

Comment: In “Example”, it seems that the properties of each group are known. You could associate variables with groups based on likelihood ratios, which also provide a measure of confidence. But in “Problem”, nothing seems to be known at all. You can’t perform inference without making assumptions; which are you making?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that they are unknown. We only have the samples (matrix M). For example, if we know that there is only one group, we only need to fit the data to a distribution.